# Customizing the "needed?" condition for a Rake task

Tags: ruby, rake

AFAIK, Rake comes with two types of tasks: `Rake::Task` which runs unconditionally, and `Rake::FileTask` which runs only if the file it is named after doesn't exist, or is older that one of its prerequisites.

Is there a conventional way to customize the logic that decides if a task needs to run? For example, if I wanted to not only verify the existence of a file, but also test its contents somehow.

I can see the method `Rake::Task#needed?` handles this, and overriding that in a subclass does indeed work. But is there a more idiomatic way to do this? Something that would be more suitable to include directly in a `Rakefile`?

I'm imagining something like this:

```
need :process do
    # Check if file is already processed
end

task :process do
    # Process file in-place
end
```

which would skip the task if all of its `need` blocks return true.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a conventional way to customize the logic that decides if a
>   task needs to run?

**Yes**; a way to do it is:

- declare the "needed tasks" as `task_1`, and let it [exist](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process.html#method-c-exit) if *needed operations* aren't proceeded
- declare the "secondary tasks" as `task_2` with [prerequisite](http://rake.rubyforge.org/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html#label-Tasks+with+Prerequisites): `task_1`

so your `rake` file will be like:

```
# check if needed is done
def needed_done?     
  return false  # TODO: edit checking logic
end

desc "do prerequisite stuff"
task :do_needed do
  p "do needed stuff"
  unless needed_done?
    p "needed stuff wasn't done ^^'"
    exit 1
  end
end

desc "process other stuff, if prerequisite is meet"
task :process  => [:do_needed] do
  p "process other stuff"
end
```

now when you ran the task `process` with:

```
rake process
```

`do_needed` will automatically ran first, if `needed_done?` then `process` will run, else you'll exit without running it